# Codeigniter | Remove index.php from site_url or anchor functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri, config

I need to remove index.php from `site_url()` return value
I don't want search engines cache my URLs contain index.php.

I removed index.php from url by setting .htaccess file but still not working.

For example, when I use site_url() in part of my project, search engines cache the URL like http://url/index.php/controller. I remove index.php from site_url function in system/helper but I think the redirect and form_open functions don't work properly.

Answer (score 12):

write in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And set index_page config in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `base_url()` function:

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/website/index.php
```

Comment: `base_url()` will return `http://example.com/website/index.php` aswell, if you have `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'` set in `config.php`

Answer (score 1):

### CodeIgniter 4

The provided answers seems to refer to an older version of CodeIgniter now the configuration are slightly different

1. Go to `/app/Config/App.php`
2. Locate `public $indexPage` Attribute and change it to:

---

```php
public $indexPage = '';
```

3. Go to `/public/.htaccess`
4. Make sure that this block of code is more or less as follow, **it should be already set this way by default**

---

```yaml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

**Using .env for configuration**

Alternativelly you can use the `.env` configuration file

1. Go to `.env`
2. Add this to the file

---

```
app.indexPage = ''
```

---

You can then use methods like without the `index.php` as trailing file

```
site_url()
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', 'title="News title"');
```

### Documentation

- [Envirorment Variables](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html?highlight=config#environment-variables)
- [site_url](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url)
- [Anchor](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor)